# Service worker not allowing PWA to show offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that isn't working offline. Online it work great but when I switch over to offline it doesn't do anything. I've suspect it's got something to do with my service-worker.js file -

```
var dataCacheName = 'sigmaApp';
var cacheName = 'sigmaApp';
var filesToCache = [
  "/", 
  "./images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
  "./images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
  "./images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
  "./images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
  "./images/icons/icon-256x256.png",
  "./images/create-how-boxes.png",
  "./images/create-how-lines.png",
  "./images/create-what-logo-1.png",
  "./images/create-what-logo-2.png",
  "./images/create-who-telkomsel.png",
  "./images/create-who-volvo.png",
  "./images/create-who-windstream.png",
  "./images/create-why-hand.png",
  "./images/create-why-rock.png",
  "./images/deliver-what-logo-1.png",
  "./images/deliver-what-logo-2.png",
  "./images/deliver-why-road-orange.png",
  "./images/deliver-why-roads.png",
  "./images/sell-how-phone.png",
  "./images/sell-how-sphere.png",
  "./images/sell-what-logo-1.png",
  "./images/sell-what-logo-1.png",
  "./images/sell-what-logo-2.png",
  "./images/sell-why-block.png",
  "./images/sell-why-hand.png",
  "./images/telkomsel-logo.png",
  "./scripts",
  "./index.html",
  "./manifest.json",
  "./scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js",
  "./scripts/swiper.min.js",
  "./scripts/swiper.min.js.map",
  "./scripts/tube-animation.min.js",
  "./scripts/typeit.min.js",
  "./scripts/scripts.js",
  "./service-worker.js",
  "./styles",
  "./styles/style.min.css",
  "./videos/create-what-infographic-1.mp4",
  "./scripts/swiper.min.js.map"
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== cacheName && key !== dataCacheName) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

My page seems to error out saying - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed in my service-worker.js file in my install event listener. I feel like it's going through the filesToCache array and erroring out there.

Does anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, go to the Network tab of the DevTools and reload your page. You will see the request that's failing.

Comment: This is on a remote server? Can you share the URL? Have you checked with the Chrom Lighthouse tools for errors?

Comment: @Mathias no this is on a live server - https://silly-kilby-fbefb5.netlify.com/. Lighthouse just keeps saying that a service worker isn't being registered but in the console it's saying it is registered.

Comment: @abadalyan - In my network tab it's saying the folders styles and scripts are 404'ing. But they both exist - silly-kilby-fbefb5.netlify.com

Comment: When I look at the Dev Tools>Application>Service Worker, it tells me that your service worker was deleted. That's odd, sorry I have no idea what causes that.

Comment: I'll make a very wild guess. It may have something to do with the number of things you are loading are causing the PWA check to timeout??? I see this message under the PWA section: "start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline
Timed out waiting for fetched start_url."

Comment: I'm seeing that https://silly-kilby-fbefb5.netlify.com/scripts/main.js, https://silly-kilby-fbefb5.netlify.com/scripts/konami.js and https://silly-kilby-fbefb5.netlify.com/scripts/pwacompat.min.js are failing with 404. Make sure that these files are present in the scripts folder.

Comment: Once try registering service without caching anything and see if error persist or not,if not then the error lies within one of your cached files

Comment: Thanks for the help all! Turns out I was including the same file twice (doh!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was my fault. I had accidentally added two files that were the same so it was erroring out because of that.

```
"./images/sell-what-logo-1.png",
"./images/sell-what-logo-1.png",
```

Hopefully this helps someone else